# Python fractal tree recursive to iteration

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

I am trying to make a code that produces the same output as this code, but is iterative. I have tried everything I can think of. Can someone please help.

Here is the code:

```
import turtle

def tree(branchLen,t):
    if branchLen > 1:
        t.forward(branchLen)
        t.right(20)
        tree(branchLen-10,t)
        t.color("blue")
        t.left(40)
        tree(branchLen-10,t)
        t.color("red")
        t.right(20)
        t.backward(branchLen)

def main():
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    myWin = turtle.Screen()
    t.left(90)
    t.up()
    t.backward(100)
    t.down()
    t.color("green")
    tree(40,t)
    myWin.exitonclick()

main()
```

Comment: Please update your question with this `"everything I can think of"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it iterative you can use this:

```
import turtle


def tree(branch_len, t):
    branches = []
    t.forward(branch_len)
    branches.append({'x': t.xcor(),
                     'y': t.ycor(),
                     'angle': t.heading()})
    while branch_len > 1:
        new_branches = []
        for branch in branches:
            t.up()
            t.goto(branch.get('x'), branch.get('y'))
            t.setheading(branch.get('angle'))
            t.down()
            t.right(20)
            t.forward(branch_len)
            new_branches.append({'x': t.xcor(),
                                 'y': t.ycor(),
                                 'angle': t.heading()})
            t.up()
            t.goto(branch.get('x'), branch.get('y'))
            t.down()
            t.left(40)
            t.forward(branch_len)
            new_branches.append({'x': t.xcor(),
                                 'y': t.ycor(),
                                 'angle': t.heading()})

        branches = new_branches
        branch_len -= 10


def main():
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    my_win = turtle.Screen()
    t.left(90)
    t.up()
    t.backward(100)
    t.down()
    t.color("green")
    tree(40,t)
    my_win.exitonclick()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```